# How do I recursively shred an entire directory tree?

Tags: security, rm, data-destruction

I have a directory tree that I would like to shred with the Linux 'shred' utility.  Unfortunately, shred has no `-R` option for recursive shredding.

**How can I shred an entire directory tree recursively?**

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use the `find` command to execute `shred -uvz` recursively:

```
find <dir> -type f -exec shred -uvz {} \;
```

**-u** ensures that after the shred operation is completed, the file is unallocated and removed.

**-v** enables verbose output for tracking the shred progress

**-z** performs a final zero-ization of the file to hide that the allocation on disk was shredded.

It should also be noted that `shred` assumes that the file system overwrites data in-place on disk, which excludes journaled (ext3/4, XFS, etc) and copy-on-write filesystems (btrfs, zfs, etc). This means that shred may not work on a per-file basis for your filesystem.

Comment: Does it work without the -depth option? Does it work on modern, journaling file systems?

Comment: @userunknown No, shred does not work on modern journaling file systems. For more precise information, please see `man shred`.

Comment: Also note that this method will *not even attempt to erase filenames*, so any data stored like this will definitely be left behind (`srm` from @Cookie's answer will at least attempt to nerf this problem).

Comment: Use `-exec shred {} +` to make it faster since shred accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: Changing it to `-exec shred --remove=wipe {} +` will also attempt to obliterate the filenames - although still with the caveat that it's hard to be sure something is really gone from modern filesystems and storage devices.

Comment: Adding to @poolie's comment, `--remove=wipesync` will do what wipe does but additionally ensure the obfuscated bytes are synced to disk. This can be more expensive but makes sure nothing is left behind (keep in mind shred's disclaimer). Note that `wipesync` is the default behavior if you supply `-u`. (based on shred version 8.31)

Comment: @ExecutionByFork (cute name) I think syncing after each individual file is going to be much slower, for no added value, versus syncing once after deleting the whole tree.

Answer (score 35):

**Beware of shred!**

From the shred-manpage:

> CAUTION: Note that shred relies on a very important assumption: that the file system overwrites data in place.
> This is the  traditional  way  to  do  things, but many modern file system designs do not satisfy this assumption.
> The following are examples of file systems on which shred is not effective, or is not guaranteed to be effective in all file system modes:
>
> - log-structured or journaled file systems, such as those supplied with AIX and Solaris (and JFS, ReiserFS, XFS, Ext3, etc.)
> - file systems that write redundant data and carry on even if some writes fail, such as RAID-based file systems
> - file systems that make snapshots, such as Network Appliance's NFS server
> - file systems that cache in temporary locations, such as NFS version 3 clients
> - compressed file systems
>
> In the case of ext3 file systems, the above disclaimer applies (and shred is thus of limited effectiveness) only in  data=journal mode, which journals file data in addition to just metadata. In both the data=ordered (default) and data=writeback modes, shred works as usual. Ext3 journaling modes can be changed by adding the data=something option to the mount options for  a  particular file system in the /etc/fstab file, as documented in the mount man page (man mount).
>
> In  addition, file system backups and remote mirrors may contain copies of the file that cannot be removed, and that will allow a shredded file to be recovered later.

Also, SSDs [might thwart](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk#Flash_memory) your attempts of overwriting data.

**Solution:** Use an encrypted filesystem, and just delete your files.

Comment: +1 for pointer on shred, I had a similar case before. It did not work on NetApp's NFS. NetApp uses WAFL and which uses copy-on-write including metajournalling, so its right. Also with latest Solaris' ZFS is another case where shred sheds.

Comment: This is a bad solution. An encrypted file system is only safe so long as it locked (and so unmounted). As soon as your OS is up and running, the data is up-for-grabs.

Comment: @oleks: Both the usage of `shred` and data encryption prevent reading the data off an offline storage device (think theft or police) with data encryption having the added benefit of protecting all files, not just the ones (properly) deleted. Once the file system is mounted we're back to good ol' unix permissions in either case and data protection becomes a task of OS security and proper system administration again. Upfront filesystem encryption is **definitely not worse** at protecting data at rest than strategic usage of `shred`!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is about someone who does already have files they want to shred.

Comment: How could companies ever practically comply with GDPR if file- and operating systems make it so hard and untransparant to destroy information.

Answer (score 28):

Use secure delete instead.

```
sudo apt-get install secure-delete
srm -r pathname
```

Done. Secure delete is a lot more paranoid than shred, using 38 passes instead of 3. To do a fast single pass, use

```
srm -rfll pathname
```

fll gets you a less random data generator, and only a single pass.

Comment: Does it solve the issue mentioned in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27075/18886 ?

Comment: How could it? No

Comment: Note that this method has the additional benefit over the proposed `find`-based methods that will try to also erase stored filenames by renaming files before truncating and unlinking them.

Comment: @ntninja find-based methods use shred and shred does rename files before finishing to delete them. So same benefits right?

Comment: `srm -rfll` v3.1 seems noticeably slower than the `find -exec shred` alternatives, as if it is still syncing even though asked not to.

Answer (score 15):

Combining this answer with the best known options for shred using this stack overflow link '[Deleting Files Permanently and Securely on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377393/deleting-files-permanently-and-securely-on-centos)':

```
find <directory> -depth -type f -exec shred -v -n 1 -z -u {} \;
```

Edit:
Be aware that *best answer* for shredding a single file forces a sync which writes changes to the media before deleting the file because some or all journaled filesystems have a buffer.

If possible, the find command should call a shell script on the file which runs:

```
shred -v -n 1 /path/to/your/file #overwriting with random data
sync #forcing a sync of the buffers to the disk
shred -v -n 0 -z -u /path/to/your/file #overwriting with zeroes and remove the file
```

on each file.

Comment: After reading and researching many answers, I found (imho) this answer to be the most thorough. I would only add to it that since shred does not remove directories I appended `rm -rvf $1` to the shell script (where $1 is the /path/to/your/file passed in from the `{}` expansion in the `find... -exec`)

Comment: shred already does a fsync(2) after each pass. Precisely because you need to force the file changes to reach the disk before the next pass.

Comment: What does `depth` do here?  Also unsure about the trailing backslash

Comment: -depth is usually used to reverse order of showing dir name match and file match inside *that* dir. If dir comes first and you delete it, you can't continue with files inside it anymore. With '-depth' dir itself will be listed after all its files if it matches. It does not make sense to use it together with -type f, but it will do no harm and with it, if sometime later you add rm -r, you'll avoid wasting time on an error. '\' is still the good old escape character. Used for ';' as shell would like to steal it, but it belongs to 'find'. Also `';'` would do instead of `\;`

Answer (score 7):

```
find /your/directory -exec shred {} \;
```

Comment: Upvoted, but James beat you by one minute for the accept.

Comment: Does it work without the -depth option? Does it work on modern, journaling file systems?

Answer (score 6):

```
find [dirname] -depth -type f -exec shred -n1 {} \;
```

This performs a depth-first search for files in directory [dirname], then runs the `shred -n1` command on each file. When removing files and/or directories, adding `-depth` as default is a good habit, even though it's not strictly needed for this case. When running this sort of command with `rm -rf` instead of `shred`, `-depth` is needed to ensure that directories are not deleted before the contents of the directories are attempted to be deleted (thus causing errors).

Answer (score 1):

Note that `shred` is an utility from GNU coreutils, it has nothing to do with Linux, other than Linux being just a kernel, operating systems using that kernel need to pick other software from elsewhere, and the GNU project has historically been the primary source for most. For basic utilities, busybox and toybox are other options and both happen to also include a `shred` utility with an interface designed after the GNU implementation though with a reduced feature set.

Now, several things to take into consideration:

Files on Unix-like systems can be of several different types: regular, fifo, directory, symlink, device, socket... All except *socket* can be *opened*, most can be read and written, but not all of them you'd want `shred` to shred when going through the  list. In particular,

- opening a symlink opens the target of a symlink, so letting `shred` shred arbitrary symlinks could lead you to shred any  file on the filesystem.
- Shredding `/dev/sda` would shred the whole contents of a disk
- a fifo is an inter-process communication tool, writing random data there would not make sense. The GNU implementation of `shred` rejects files of type *fifo*.

You likely want to only shred files of type:

- *regular*
- *directory* (if the file names are also sensitives).

But for the latter, while GNU `shred` has a `--remove=wipe` for that, it can only do it for one directory entry, so couldn't do it for the other entries (including the ones for files of different types, or the entries that have been removed without being wiped before).

It's also not possible to selectively shred files of a given type in a race-free way. For instance, you could determine a file is a *regular* file, but that file be replaced with a symlink by the time `shred` is invoked to wipe it.

Also note that if some of the files are being actively written, `shred` will fail to wipe the parts that have been written after it was invoked.

So, the best you can do with GNU `shred` is:

```
find dir -depth ! -type f -delete -o -exec shred -f --remove=wipe {} ';'
```

So besides all the limitations with shredding already mentioned by others, the limitations with this *recursive* shredding approach are also:

- it will not fully shred directory contents (the name of the files within).
- it may not full shred files that are still being written (even if they are deleted)
- it could end up shredding files of the wrong type. You'd want not to do that on directories writable by others as that could introduce security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The most thorough `shred` method I've found, which includes directory removal too, is to have `find` call a script to have `shred`:

- overwrite the file
- sync
- then delete
- and finally call rm to remove the directory names.

This method also properly handles filenames with spaces in them.

First - the `shred` script (I've named mine `dirShredder.sh` and stored it in the `/root` directory:

```
shred -v -n 1 "$1" #overwriting with random data
sync #forcing a sync of the buffers to the disk
shred -v -n 0 -z -u "$1" #overwriting with zeroes and remove the file
rm -rvf "$1" # call rm to remove the directories
```

Then, call the script like this:

```
find /volume1/pathToShred/ -mindepth 1 -depth -exec /root/dirShredder.sh "{}" \;
```

Make sure to mark the `killit.sh` file executable (`chmod +x`) and of course update the path for the dir you want to shred and to `dirShredder.sh` if you store it somewhere else.

NOTA BENE - `shred` has issues on Copy-on-Write filesystems (ZFS, BTRFS, et al) and even on Journaling file systems.  There is no real accepted "best" way to deal with this that I've found other than "encrypted filesystems" but I'm not sure how effective this is after-the-fact.
The closest it seems you can get is to overwrite all empty space on the drive with random data after your shredding ops (not zeros, seems this is not always reliable.)  Also, SSDs may have other considerations too (like TRIM.)

I'm not going into those here, there are other Stack answers (@user unknown's answer in this question for example) and plenty of discussions throughout the 'net that cover these topics so search them out if you need that level of security.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
shred yourDirectory/*
```

Go check your file, they're unreadable :)

```
rm -r yourDirectory
```

Comment: The issue here is that `shred` is only applied to the visible entries at the first level under `yourDirectory` whereas the question asks how one may apply it to all files in a hierarchy.

Comment: That only shreds the non-hidden files directly in `yourDirectory`, not the ones in subdirectories and it fails to  shred the hidden ones unless you change the default behaviour of your shell globs to include them.