# Remove a lot of cache files

Tags: linux, rm, cache

There are over 1m+ cache files in one directory on a server. I would need to remove them, but of course `rm` first lists file and then starts to remove them.
That cause a high spike in a server CPU load and can cause whole server to break down.
Any ideas how to safely remove them without causing any harm?

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37329 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you value more cpu usage than speed on the erase, this is a good approach:

```
find <dir> -type f -exec ionice -c3 rm {} \;
```

Replace `\;` with `+` if you want some more speed (and more cpu).