# recursive delete with sftp?

Tags: recursive, sftp

I have a host that I can only access with sftp, scp, and rsync-- no ssh. I have a large tree of directories that I want to delete, but my sftp client apparently does not support recursive `rm`s or `rmdir`s. In the help screen, it shows I can do recursive `put`s, but that doesn't help me.

How can I delete my files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `lftp` client to do this. The the `-r` option to `lftp rm` recursively deletes directories and files.

```
$ lftp -u <user>,<pass> <server> 
lftp> rm -r <directory>
```

#### References

- [lftp main website](http://lftp.yar.ru/)

Answer (score 1):

rsync has several delete options -

```
--delete            delete extraneous files from dest dirs
--delete-before     receiver deletes before xfer, not during
--delete-during     receiver deletes during the transfer
--delete-delay      find deletions during, delete after
--delete-after      receiver deletes after transfer, not during
--delete-excluded   also delete excluded files from dest dirs
```

any of these should remove files on your host once deleted from your local copy.

An example how to delete the content of an entire directory can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79656/359521).

Comment: rsync doesn't support sftp. Also, a concrete example might help to explain how to use these options better.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs The question states `I can only access with sftp, scp, and rsync` - it isn't asking about *only* sftp.

Comment: That's kind of a weird way, but yeah, to empty a directory: `mkdir a && rsync -r --delete a/ user@host:path`.