# Perl script to delete big directory

Tags: linux, command-line, perl, rm

[This](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux) blog gives different ways of deleting Big Directories and their relative times for deleting a directory with 500,000 files. The script using `perl` is reported to be fastest, which is given by

```
cd yourdirectory
perl -e 'for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
```

This answer is also reported in StackExchange-Unix&Linux [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79656/17621). The current script can only delete files just one level under the directory. Can anyone provide an equivalent `perl` script that deletes all subdirectories and their contents recursively?

Comment: What's wrong with using `rm -Rf`?

Comment: agreed with Jan - the blog article referenced in the question seemed to give up too easily when "rm -f *" failed. cd .. and rm -rf the directory.

Comment: What is that `stat` call doing, and why is it in a boolean context with the `unlink` ?? (A more legible Perl answer would quite possibly involve `File::Path qw/remove_tree/`.)

Comment: @thrig: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28715226/2218718) for more details.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: `rm -rf` can fail with error argument list too long for huge files.

Comment: I saw that @cuonglm, which is why I was unimpressed when the article didn't simplify with "cd ..; rm -rf the_directory" (only one argument to rm) -- or did you mean to imply that `rm -rf directory` could fail if there are too many files in the directory?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Ah, I mean `rm -rf *`