# How does iotop calculate the relative I/O activity?

Tags: performance, io, disk, top

I am running some heavy I/O processes on my workstation and recently installed `iotop` to monitor them. Here's a recent screenshot:

[image: iotop screenshot]

I'm a bit confused about the readings in the `IO>` column. It indicates my disk is running at around ~1500% I/O activity. Is that even possible?

How to figure out the maximum possible I/O of my disk from these readings? And how does iotop calculate the relative I/O activity?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`iotop` shows statistics from several different origins; take care when adding up stuff.

[This previous discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248197/iotop-showing-1-5-mb-s-of-disk-write-but-all-programs-have-0-00-b-s/248218#248218) covers the difference between per-process read/write amounts and the system total read/write amounts: they cover different stuff since the per-process amounts include all I/O (whether to disk, to cache, to network, etc.) whereas the system total is between RAM and disk (including swap, delayed cache writes, etc.).

You can't add up numbers from the `IO>` column. They show what fraction of *each process's time* is spent on I/O, not what fraction of total I/O comes from each process. 99.9% means that this process is pretty much always blocked on I/O.

Accounting for I/O by process is difficult since a lot of I/O is shared between processes (cache of files used by multiple processes, a process requesting RAM causing another process to be swapped out, etc.)

I don't think there's a useful definition of the “maximum possible I/O” of a disk. There's a maximum sequential write speed and a maximum sequential read speed at different points of the chain (`hdparm -t` displays some of these values), but that isn't really indicative of actual usage. Reading and writing files is typically not sequential; on a hard disk, moving heads to access a different location is often what takes the most time.

Comment: Those percentages shown indicate snapshots in time, would be nice if it showed a moving average across all time.