# What's the fastest way to remove all files & subfolders in a directory?

Tags: linux, deleted-files

One program created lots of nested sub-folders. I tried to use command
 `rm -fr *` to remove them all. But it's very slow. I'm wondering is there any faster way to delete them all?

Comment: The fastest method is described here.  perl is by far the fastest for files.  Then rm to get the empty  directories.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37329/efficiently-delete-large-directory-containing-thousands-of-files

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The fastest way to remove them from that directory is to move them out of there, after that just remove them in the background:

```
mkdir ../.tmp_to_remove
mv -- * ../.tmp_to_remove
rm -rf ../.tmp_to_remove &
```

This assumes that your current directory is not the toplevel of some mounted partition (i.e. that `../.tmp_to_remove` is on the same filesystem).

The `--` after `mv` (as edited in by Stéphane) is necessary if you have any file/directory names starting with a `-`.

The above removes the files from your current directory in a fraction of a second, as it doesn't have to recursively handle the subdirectories. The actual removal of the tree from the filesystem takes longer, but since it is out of the way, its actual efficiency shouldn't matter that much.

Comment: @ndemou, never say `.*` it matches `..` bad things can happen. (but in this case only an error message.)

Comment: The 2nd command won't match any .dot files. To really delete *all* files including .dot files use this command: `mv -- * .??* .[!.] ../.tmp_to_remove`. Note that `*` matches all non .dot file names, `.??*` matches all dot files with a file name of 3 or more characters and `.[!.]` matches all dot files with a file name of exactly 2 characters except `..` -- Thanks to @Jasen for leading me to this path (the result is not pretty but is correct).

Comment: This won't help if you are out-of-space and trying to free up some space by deleting a folder which has significant number of files. The disk and inode usage would remain same in this approach.

Comment: @SayanBose Are you claiming that the third command (`rm -rf ...`) will not work when you are out of space? In my experience that is untrue: even if the disk is at 100% the above steps allow you to clean out a directory almost immediately,(getting free space on your disk of course requires more time).

Comment: @Anthon, No, rm -rf will work when you are out of disk space. Your mkdir won't work if you are out of disk space or inodes.

Comment: “in the background” is thus not actually fast and still requires more computational power than more efficient solutions. The OP already said `rm -rf` is slow, and your answer does not change that.

Comment: @MSBerends The OP asks "What's the fastest way to remove all files & subfolders in a directory", so you shouldn't count the time it takes to clean up after achieving the goal, or convince the OP of accepting a different answer.

Comment: I kindly disagree :) To me "having dinner with the family tonight" includes preparing the meal and cleaning the kitchen afterwards, but that might be personal. I would indeed suggest the OP to accept the answer of Rahul, since using `rsync` is faster in this case (and an ingenious solution btw) and thus the better answer IMHO.

Answer (score 25):

`rsync` is surprisingly fast and simple. You have to create empty directory first,

```
mkdir emptydir
rsync -a --delete emptydir/ yourdirectory/
```

`yourdirectory/` is the directory from where you want to remove the files.

Comment: Interesting use of `rsync`. Is it faster than `rm`?

Comment: @pfnuesel : Yes, see this answer http://serverfault.com/a/328305/105902.

Comment: I've had to copy thousands of files from one drive to another. Using cp it crashed the server, eating up all memory. Rsync did the trick without a problem - although I kept htop open in a separate session to kill it when needed. So rsync can be a very useful tool.

Answer (score 10):

The fastest is with `rm -rf dirname`. I used a snapshotted mountpoint of an ext3 filesystem on RedHat6.4 with 140520 files and 9699 directories. If `rm -rf *` is slow, it might be because your top-level directory entry has *lots* of files, and the shell is busy expanding `*`, which requires an additional readdir and sort. Go up a directory and do `rm -rf dirname/`.

```
Method                    Real time    Sys time  Variance (+/-)
find dir -delete          0m8.108s     0m3.668s  0.055s
rm -rf dir                0m7.956s     0m3.640s  0.081s
rsync -delete empty/ dir/ 0m8.305s     0m3.918s  0.029s
```

Notes:

- rsync version : 3.0.6
- rm/coreutils version: 8.4-19
- find/findutils version: 4.4.2-6

Comment: Confirmed that. I have 1 million files to delete, spread over 3000 directories that contains thousands of subdirectories inside. Using the find method I was able to delete one directory per minute. Using the rm -rf dirname I am able to delete 1 directories every 2 seconds.  I am using this bash command: `for d in */;do rm -rf $d;done`. thanks.

Answer (score 9):

One problem with `rm -rf *`, or its more correct equivalent `rm -rf -- *` is that the shell has first to list all the (non-hidden) files in the current directory, sort them and pass them to `rm`, which if the list of files in the current directory is big is going to add some unnecessary extra overhead, and could even fail if the list of file is too big.

Normally, you'd do `rm -rf .` instead (which would also have the benefit of deleting hidden files as well). But most `rm` implementations including all POSIX conformant ones will refuse to do that. The reason is that some shells (including all POSIX ones) have that misfeature that the expansion of `.*` glob would include `.` and `..`. Which would mean that `rm -rf .*` would delete the current and parent directory, so `rm` has been modified to work around that misfeature of those shells.

Some shells like `pdksh` (and other Forsyth shell derivatives), `zsh` or `fish` don't have that misfeature¹. `zsh` has a `rm` builtin which you can enable with `autoload zsh/files` that, since `zsh`'s `.*` doesn't include `.` nor `..` works OK with `rm -rf .`. So in `zsh`, you can do:

```
zmodload zsh/files
rm -rf .
```

On Linux, you can do:

```
rm -rf /proc/self/cwd/
```

to empty the current directory or:

```
rm -rf /dev/fd/3/ 3< some/dir
```

to empty an arbitrary directory.

(note the trailing `/`)

On GNU systems, you can do:

```
find . -delete
```

Now, if the current directory only has a few entries and the bulk of the files are in subdirs, that won't make a significant difference and `rm -rf -- *` will probably be the fastest you can get. It's expected for `rm -rf` (or anything that removes every file) to be expensive as it means reading the content of all directories and calling `unlink()` on every entry. `unlink()` itself can be quite expensive as it involves modifying the deleted file's inode, the directory containing the file, and some file system map or other of what areas are free.

`rm` and `find` (at least the GNU implementations) already sort the list of files by inode number in each directory which can make a huge difference in terms of performance on ext4 file systems as it reduces the number of changes to the underlying block devices when consecutive (or close to each other) inodes are modified in sequence.

`rsync` sorts the files by name which could drastically reduce performance unless the by-name order happens to match the by-inum order (like when the files have been created from a sorted list of file names).

One reason why `rsync` may be faster in some cases is that it doesn't appear to take safety precautions to avoid race conditions that could cause it to descend into the wrong directory if a directory was replaced with a symlink while it's working like `rm` or `find` do.

To optimize a bit further:

If you know the maximum depth of your directory tree, you can pass it to `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -delete
```

That saves `find` having to try and read the content of the directories at depth 3.

---

<sup>¹ see also the `globskipdots` option in bash 5.2+</sup>

Comment: _"if the list of file is *too* big."_

Comment: In the last paragraph you talk about `rm -rf` being an expensive operation as it calls `unlink()` on all entry, but is that not what `find . -delete` would do too?

Comment: @fduff, yes. Like I say (maybe not clearly), `find -delete` won't make much difference if there are few files in the current directory, The only difference would be about avoiding creating and sorting and pass around that big list.