# I've accidentally written 4 million small text files to a folder, how best to get rid of them?

Tags: files, find, rm

Due to a script error (`file_put_contents($text, $filename, FILE_APPEND)` instead of `file_put_contents($filename, $text, FILE_APPEND)` I now have 4 million small text files in a folder.

I'd rather not nuke the whole folder, as a handful of useful files are in there.

All of the unwanted files have "jpg" in the middle of the filename, none of the wanted files do.

What's the quickest way to delete these?  I can't even do a `ls` without it hanging my console at the moment - which makes identifying the names of the files I want to keep hard, otherwise I'd just move them out of the folder and then delete the whole folder.

Is `find . -name "*jpg*" -delete` the best option, or is there a better/quicker way?

Comment: So, none of the wanted files have `jpg` in the name in the middle, or anywhere at all?

Comment: Correct, they don't contain that string in their name at all.

Comment: `rm -f /location/of/many/files/*jpg*`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure which would be more efficient, that or find.

Comment: You can do de opposite, move the wanted files to a new dir: `find . ! -name '*jpg* -exec mv -t path {} +` and once you are sure you have your files, nuke the dir.

Comment: `bash: /usr/bin/rm: Argument list too long`

Comment: `find /location/of/many/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*jpg*' -delete`

Comment: My bad, forgot about that , yeah, looks like `find` is the way in this case.

Comment: It's my home directory @guillermo chamorro, so I was a bit nervous about doing that in case I caused problems moving some hidden `.bash_whatever`, ssh files etc.  Could I accidentally kill my session and prevent myself by logging back in using your method?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277203/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37329/117549

Comment: Yes, forget about it, I thought you had a dedicated dir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With 4 million files, `rm /location/of/many/files/*jpg*` will probably fail with `Argument list too long` error.

Use `find`:

```
find /location/of/many/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*jpg*' -delete
```

or if `-delete` is not available:

```
find /location/of/many/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*jpg*' -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: This is what I've gone with.  Half an hour in and it's deleted half of the files.

Comment: So use a better filesystem, like e.g. ZFS. BTW: `find -delete` is nonstandard and non-portable. `find -exec rm {} +` is not slower and portable.

Comment: Thanks, I added that information.

Comment: @Codemonkey, there is probably a way to use `rsync` for this; it's going to be faster than `find`.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79656/135943