# Remove everything within directory using for loop

Tags: files, directory, for, dot-files

I am trying to remove large amount of mails (mostly mail delivery failed) from my server using

```
 rm -rf /home/*/mail/new/*
```

And I am getting `-bash: /usr/bin/rm: Argument list too long`

I tried using find

```
find /home/*/mail/new/ -mindepth 1 -delete
```

But after 20 minutes it looks like it's not doing anything.

How do I use for loop to delete everything (directories, files, dotfiles) within `/home/*/mail/new/`

Something like this

```
for f in /home/*/mail/new/*.*~; do
        # if it is a file, delete it
    if [  -f $f ]
    then
        rm "$f"
    fi
done
```

Please help me rewrite this command to delete files AND folders and everything within `/home/*/mail/new/`

EDIT:
My question is unique because it's about doing that in FOR loop.

Comment: The `find` command looks fine. If you want to show what it's, doing use `-print -delete`

Comment: I think `for` has better performance than find.

Comment: It doesn't. Shell loops are *slow*. Nothing will be slower than the loop and `find` should be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: see also [Efficiently delete large directory containing thousands of files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37329)

Comment: not duplicate. That is not what question is about,  i asked how to remove all files, folders and dotfiles using for loop, and there is no answer on internet for that.

Comment: you could start splitting the loops up -- `for d in /home/*; do rm -rf "/home/$d/mail/....` and even sections of filenames from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `/home/*/mail/new/*` expands to too many file names. The simplest solution is to delete the directory instead:

```
rm -rf /home/*/mail/new/
```

Alternatively, use your `find` command. It should work, it will just be slower.

Or, if you need the `new` directories use a loop to find them, delete and recreate them:

```
for d in /home/*/mail/new/; do
    rm -rf "$d" && mkdir "$d"
done
```

The loop you were trying to write (but don't use this, it is very slow and inefficient) is something like:

```
for f in /home/*/mail/new/* /home/*/mail/new/.*; do
    rm -rf "$f"
done
```

No need to test for files if you want to delete everything, just use `rm -rf` and both directories and files can be deleted by the same command. It will complain about not being ab;e to delete `.` and `..` but you can ignore that. Or, if you want to be super clean and avoid the errors, you can do this in bash:

```
shopt -s dotglob
for f in /home/*/mail/new/*; do
        rm -rf "$f"
done
```

Comment: Then my only solution is to delete whole `new` directory and recreate it.

Comment: @Luka no, you can use your `find` command and wait a bit. But yes, deleting and recreating is by far the easiest and fastest way. I also added the loop you were asking for but that will be far slower than anything else.

Comment: I added `nice -n -20` to find command, and its a lot faster

Comment: @Luka OK, that suggests you have a pretty busy machine and other things were taking precedence. The main take home message here is that *shell loops are slow and inefficient*, pretty much *anything* will be faster than a shell loop.