# Using rsync to delete selected patterns, matches all files

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync, quoting

I mean to use `rsync` to remove certain files (for [Efficiently delete large directory containing thousands of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37329/efficiently-delete-large-directory-containing-thousands-of-files)), in this case given to a shell script as patterns in the command line.

So far, this is what I have in my shell script `rsync_del.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_DIR=${1}
shift
PATTERNS="${@}"
for patt in ${PATTERNS} ; do
    # Both do the same
    #INCLUDE_PATTERNS="${INCLUDE_PATTERNS}"' --include='\'"${patt}"\'
    INCLUDE_PATTERNS="${INCLUDE_PATTERNS} --include=\"${pattern}\""
done

EMPTYDIR=$(mktemp -d)
echo "Created empty dir ${EMPTYDIR}"
comm="rsync -a --progress --delete ${INCLUDE_PATTERNS} ${EMPTYDIR}/ ${TARGET_DIR}"
echo ${comm}
eval ${comm}
```

Example patterns that I would like to use are `*[1-9].txt`, `*000??9.txt`.
The problem is that, when executing

```
rsync_del.sh trg_dir '*[1-9].txt'
```

the command line generated is

```
rsync -a --progress --delete --include='*[1-9].txt' /tmp/tmp.51R9hPgkfG/ trg_dir/
```

(which seems ok to me), but it is matching, e.g., files like `input.dat` (and I don't want that).

**What is the correct way of implementing/using this?**
I suspect it is a matter of properly escaping patterns, but I could not make this work.

Note: I need to define the command to be executed in a variable, to `echo` it prior to executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that I should close the pattern list by excluding anything not explicitly included.
I used

```
comm="rsync -a --progress --delete ${INCLUDE_PATTERNS} --exclude=\"*\" ${EMPTYDIR}/ ${TARGET_DIR}"
```

Comment: Or is this an answer to your own question (which is fine to do)?

Comment: @roaima - I edited the answer... Yes, it is an answer to my own question.

Comment: @JigglyNaga - Both question and answer were complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not looking too closely at the actual *use* of `rsync` here and instead concentrating on the creation of the `rsync` command line.

```
#!/bin/bash

target=$1
shift

empty=$( mktemp -d )

trap 'rmdir "$empty"' EXIT

for pattern do
   incl+=( --include="$pattern" )
done

rsync --archive --progress --delete "${incl[@]}" --exclude='*' "$empty"/ "$target"
```

By using an array (the `incl` array above), you store the arguments to `rsync` separately and not like a string. The expansion of `"${incl[@]}"` will be the individually quoted elements of the array.  Quoting the arguments becomes trivial and there is no need to call `eval`.  Note also that all parameter expansions need to be properly double quoted.

The issue with your code is that you use most parameter expansions unquoted. This makes the shell perform word splitting and filename generation (globbing) on the variables. This in turn means that you can not use patterns containing spaces or shell globbing patterns that may expand to names of existing files.

---

For `/bin/sh` the syntax becomes even less verbose:

```
#!/bin/sh

target=$1
shift

empty=$( mktemp -d )

trap 'rmdir "$empty"' EXIT

for pattern do
   set -- "$@" --include="$pattern"
   shift
done

rsync --archive --progress --delete "$@" --exclude='*' "$empty"/ "$target"
```

Comment: Thanks. Use of `eval` was only to be able to `echo` the command line to be used, as a reference and to possibly copy and reuse it with minor variations.

Comment: Perhaps it should be `for pattern in ... ; do`

Comment: @sancho.s No, the loop, when written as I have done above, will loop over the positional parameters correctly.

Comment: Is there any advantage with using the array? It seems to produce exactly the same result.
+1 Even if it was not the cause of the problem of the OP, you identified the need for escaping, so I changed my line to enclose `${INCLUDE_PATTERNS}` in the double quotes to avoid local expansion.

Comment: @sancho.s You should do some standard tests with that such as using a pattern with spaces (maybe `'* *'` to match filenames that contain spaces) and a pattern that contain a filename pattern that matches a file in the current directory (maybe `'*.txt'` or just `'*'`).