# How to get find -exec to call a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, find

Taking from the last answer (by im3r3k) here: [How do I recursively shred an entire directory tree?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27027/how-do-i-recursively-shred-an-entire-directory-tree)

I'm trying to get the `find` command to call a shell script as described.

So far I've tried:

```
find /home/shredtest/* -depth -exec /home/test.sh {}\;
```

where `/home/shredtest` is the directory whose contents I want to shred (but without removing `/home/shredtest` itself and where `/home/test.sh` is the script to run. I did `chmod +x /home/test.sh`.

The `find` command above returns:

> find: -exec CMD must end by ';'

I've also tried:

```
find /home/shredtest/* -depth -exec /home/test.sh "{}"\;
find /home/shredtest/* -depth -exec /home/test.sh {}\;
find /home/shredtest/* -depth -exec sh /home/test.sh "{}"\;
find /home/shredtest/* -depth -exec sh \/home\/test.sh {}\;
find /home/shredtest/* -depth -exec sh \/home\/test.sh "{}"\;
```

all of which return the same error.

So:

1. Why is the `-exec` failing to see the semicolon?  Obviously it's there and escaped so something else must be wrong.  I just don't see it.
2. Am I even going about this the right way or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `;` has to be its own separate argument to `find`:

```
find /home/shredtest/ -depth -exec /home/test.sh "{}" \;
```

(note space between `{}` and `\;`). After `-exec`:

> All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.

(from [`man find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)). That is, the argument has to consist *entirely* of `;` to stop the argument list.

You can also use `+' to pass many file arguments at once, which has to be its own argument too.

---

Note also that in `find /home/shredtest/*` the `*` is unnecessary: `find` will go through the directory contents itself, while `*` will be expanded by the shell (and occasionally may not lead to exactly the results you wanted).

Comment: Thank you Michael, will try those suggestions shortly.  To address the * in `find /home/shredtest/*` I found, by running the find by itself, that without the trailing * the shredtest directory itself is included in the results.  With the trailing * it's not.  Is this not the right way or is there a  better way to exclude shredtest from being shreded?

Comment: You can use `-mindepth 1` to process only contents and not the command-line arguments themselves.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Michael.  Something as silly as a space derailed me for at least 45 minutes <doh>.  And mindepth seems to work a treat.  Thank you!